# ASP.NET MVC 4 Bundling not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle

I have a used the intranet template for a simple MVC 4 project.
I have tried to bundle separately my css and js.
All works ok until I change my web.config debug=false to make use of the minification.

When I run the project without debugging the application hangs and looking in firebug and fiddler it does not appear to make the requests for the bundles.

Have I missed sometin obvious?

Answer (score 13):

make sure you are not trying to minify min versions of js and that you have the latest webgrease (1.3) from nuget.